# WebView.draw(canvas) sometimes crashes in Android Lollipop 5.0+ on some devices - Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV)

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-webview, android-canvas, android-5.0-lollipop

I have a piece of code that runs on the UI thread that asks a `RelativeLayout` with a `WebView` to draw onto a `Canvas`:

```
someRelativeLayoutContainingWebView.draw(canvas);
```

This exact line crashes on some Android Lollipop 5.0 devices (Nexus 4, Nexus 5), but works on others (Nexus 7). The crash log displays the following:

```
--------- beginning of crash
F/libc    (20829): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x8d68fc68 in tid 21178 (Thread-860)
W/art     (20829): Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
I/DEBUG   (  184): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   (  184): Build fingerprint: 'google/occam/mako:5.0/LRX21T/1576899:user/release-keys'
I/DEBUG   (  184): Revision: '11'
I/DEBUG   (  184): ABI: 'arm'
I/DEBUG   (  184): pid: 20829, tid: 21178, name: Thread-860  >>> com.[censored] <<<
I/DEBUG   (  184): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x8d68fc68
I/DEBUG   (  184):     r0 8d68fc68  r1 00000020  r2 000000df  r3 20202020
I/DEBUG   (  184):     r4 00000001  r5 8d68fc68  r6 8d68fc68  r7 a62a0241
I/DEBUG   (  184):     r8 b86f9e13  r9 b86f982a  sl ffffffff  fp 000000ff
I/DEBUG   (  184):     ip 20002000  sp a32988f8  lr a62525f9  pc a62a02bc  cpsr 200b0030
I/DEBUG   (  184): 
I/DEBUG   (  184): backtrace:
I/DEBUG   (  184):     #00 pc 003552bc  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
I/DEBUG   (  184):     #01 pc 003075f7  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
I/DEBUG   (  184):     #02 pc 002c450f  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
I/DEBUG   (  184):     #03 pc 002c4589  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
I/DEBUG   (  184):     #04 pc 002c6b41  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
I/DEBUG   (  184):     #05 pc 002c6ffb  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
I/DEBUG   (  184):     #06 pc 002c4b83  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
I/DEBUG   (  184):     #07 pc 002c4c51  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
I/DEBUG   (  184):     #08 pc 002adff5  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
I/DEBUG   (  184):     #09 pc 002fea4f  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
I/DEBUG   (  184):     #10 pc 002aa35f  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
I/DEBUG   (  184):     #11 pc 0032d4ef  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
I/DEBUG   (  184):     #12 pc 002bd2d1  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
I/DEBUG   (  184):     #13 pc 00e0ef7b  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
I/DEBUG   (  184):     #14 pc 00e14a4d  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
I/DEBUG   (  184):     #15 pc 00e14af3  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
I/DEBUG   (  184):     #16 pc 00e4cbd1  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
I/DEBUG   (  184):     #17 pc 00e1ccd1  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
I/DEBUG   (  184):     #18 pc 00e1ce17  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
I/DEBUG   (  184):     #19 pc 00204333  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
I/DEBUG   (  184):     #20 pc 0020458d  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
I/DEBUG   (  184):     #21 pc 002023cb  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
I/DEBUG   (  184):     #22 pc 000158a7  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+30)
I/DEBUG   (  184):     #23 pc 0001387b  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+6)
```

The drawing is called once every second or so. The crash does not occur until the 40th - 120th time that `draw()` is called within a single run of my application. All my test devices that do not have Lollipop installed work just fine and do not crash.

The crash also does not occur if I remove the `WebView` from the `RelativeLayout`, but leave all of the other elements. The `WebView` does load a website and functions normally for a while until the crash occurs. If I do not call `loadUrl()`, then the crash does not occur. The crash occurs no matter which website I load.

Is there anything I can do to fix this?

I found some resources for the problem here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/W6smaM1atE8

However, the functions that are used in this case have been deprecated for a long time.

### EDIT:

Here's some additional info to respond to @marcin.kosiba's questions:

1. The Canvas you're passing is a Bitmap-backed Canvas, correct? How big is it? Does it have any transforms applied?

Yes, here're the preceding lines:

```
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(someRelativeLayoutContainingWebView.getWidth(), someRelativeLayoutContainingWebView.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
someRelativeLayoutContainingWebView.draw(canvas);
```

As you can see, it's the whole width and height of the `RelativeLayout`, which takes up the whole screen of the device, minus the device's status bar and soft back/home buttons bar. My application does not run in fullscreen mode.

2. The WebView is displayed on screen and being rendered into this canvas or is the WebView not attach to the view hierarchy and operated in the background?

The WebView is attached to the view hierarchy and does appear on the screen. It takes up most of the screen, minus a small bar at the top.

3. Does this happen if you call WebView.onDraw directly as well?

I am unable to call `onDraw()` directly unless I override the `WebView` class. However, upon doing so, the crash did not occur.

4. It would make it a lot easier for the person looking at this if you could create an APK with a repro and attach it to the bug. Are you willing to do so? If not, could you provide some details about the other elements in the RelativeLayout?

Unfortunately it's a pretty large project and there are a lot of things going on in the `Activity` that has this issue. I will not be able to publicly share the whole source code, which, I know, makes solving the problem more difficult. Here is a skeleton of the view hierarchy:

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/someRelativeLayoutContainingWebView">
    <DrawerLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/topRelativeLayout">

        <!-- Main content -->
        <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <WebView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/primaryWebView"
                        android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
                        android:fadeScrollbars="true"
                        android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scrollbar"
                        android:scrollbarSize="@dimen/scroll_bar_size"/>

                <RelativeLayout>
                    <EditText/>
                    <Button/>
                    <View/>
                    <Button/>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <View/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <!-- Navigation drawer -->
        <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="left">

            <RelativeLayout>
                <TextView/>
                <ViewPager/>
                <View/>

                <LinearLayout>
                    <Button/>
                    <View/>
                    <Button/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout>
                    <Button/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <Button/>
                <Button/>
                <Button/>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <View/>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </DrawerLayout>

    <!-- Top bar -->
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/some_height"
                    id="@+id/topRelativeLayout">

        <RelativeLayout>
            <SurfaceView/>
            <TextView/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <Button/>

        <RelativeLayout>
                <EditText/>
                <Button/>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <View/>
    <ProgressBar/>
    <TextView/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue came from a race condition that sometimes caused my code to draw onto a `Canvas` that belonged to a recycled `Bitmap`. The crash can be reproduced with the following code:

```
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(someRelativeLayoutContainingWebView.getWidth(), someRelativeLayoutContainingWebView.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
bmp.recycle();
someRelativeLayoutContainingWebView.draw(canvas); // SIGSEGV will happen here
```

Fixing the race condition and making sure that a recycled `Bitmap` `Canvas` is never drawn on has fixed the problem.

An additional detail that is interesting is that if the `WebView` is removed from the view hierarchy, then a `RuntimeException` is thrown instead of a `SIGSEGV` occurring. The important bits of the exception look like this:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 7052): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap@1cb64604
E/AndroidRuntime( 7052):    at android.graphics.Canvas.throwIfCannotDraw(Canvas.java:1225)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7052):    at android.graphics.Canvas.<init>(Canvas.java:152)
```

This is much more informative than the `WebView` crash.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure at this point if there is anything you can do. I filed http://crbug.com/441707 on your behalf. Knowing the cause of the problem makes it easier to come up with workarounds. It would be helpful if you could clarify some things (preferably on the bug):

1. the Canvas you're passing is a Bitmap-backed Canvas, correct? How big is it? Does it have any transforms applied?
2. The WebView is displayed on screen *and* being rendered into this canvas or is the WebView not attach to the view hierarchy and operated in the background?
3. does this happen if you call WebView.onDraw directly as well?
4. it would make it a lot easier for the person looking at this if you could create an APK with a repro and attach it to the bug. Are you willing to do so? If not, could you provide some details about the other elements in the RelativeLayout?

Comment: Thanks, I have added responses to your questions